# How to get Bootstrap panel working with ngx-bootstrap

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to add a bootstrap panel to ngx-bootstrap + angular 7 web application, somehow I am not getting the styling.
Here is an example I am trying in stackblitz 
I have added bootstrap css file in index.html.
Here is code sample
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wl7dqs

Answer (score 0):

`panel` is not available in Bootstrap 4.

If you need `panel`, better use Bootstrap 3.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vksoqn

or
else you can give a try to `card` in Bootstrap 4.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nk7srt